# Redux multiple actions

Tags: redux

I have 2 Firebase listeners, which are emitting actions on database change:

```
export function watchProfile(uid) {
  return dispatch => {
    fb.db.ref(`profiles/${uid}`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      dispatch({type: constants.UPDATE_PROFILE, payload: snapshot.val()})
    })
    fb.db.ref(`activeEvents/${uid}`).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      const eventId = snapshot.key;
      fb.db.ref(`events/${eventId}`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        dispatch({type: constants.ACTIVE_EVENT, payload: {...snapshot.val(), id: eventId}})
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Also, there is another Action. It makes changes, which are detected by both of the listeners above.
Once this "another Action" emitted, i'm getting error:

```
Reducers may not dispatch actions.
```

Why is this happening?

App is builded on top of [pepperoni-app-kit](https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit)
`redux-thunk` is added.

If i'm adding timeouts to the listeners `dispatch`, then it works fine, but, of course, this is not the solution.

```
case constants.UPDATE_PROFILE:
  return state.set('profile', fromJS(action.payload))
  break;

case constants.SUBMIT_EVENT: {
  const profile = state.get('profile').toJS();
  const eventId = action.payload;
  fb.db.ref(`activeEvents/${profile.uid}/${eventId}`).set(true);
  fb.db.ref(`profiles/${profile.uid}/totalEvents`).set(Number(profile.totalEvents) +1 || 1);
  return state
  break;
}

case constants.ACTIVE_EVENT: {
  if (typeof action.payload === 'string') {
    return state.deleteIn(['activeEvents', action.payload])
  } else {
    return state.setIn(['activeEvents', action.payload.id], action.payload)
  }
}
```

Actions:

```
SUBMIT_EVENT // the one, which triggers changes in db
UPDATE_PROFILE
ACTIVE_EVENT
```

Comment: Error you're getting would suggest to me you didn't include all relevant code. The `watchProfile` is an action creator is it? And the error is about reducer (unless you tried to use watchProfile as your reducer??)

Comment: @WTK, i've added the code

Comment: is this just because i've emitted firebase `set` queries in reducer? I've moved it to another place, and now it works. However, i don't get, how did they affected that? Queries are not emiting any actions or whatever stuff related to redux. May be it works now only because there a bit more time between actions now? In this case, bug will continue happening in some rare cases, right?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/55f1d08000b1b064eaa933bbbd132230e53bcccb/src/createStore.js#L165 it would seem that you're having this error because you modify (via `fb.db.ref`) WHILE consuming an action. This probably causes your firebase listener to fire and dispatch new action.

The reason it works when you use setTimeout is because it will fire at earliest at the next event loop, which means as far as redux is concerned you're done handling one action and it is fine to fire another.

Way to fix it would be probably by writing your own middleware (see http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#seven-examples) that will react to `constants.SUBMIT_EVENT` event and operate on `fb.db.ref...`. It will work because whilst it's forbidden to dispatch an action from a reducer, it's ok to do it from middleware context.

Just watch out for circular updates - if you'll keep updating an item in Firebase which will fire "onUpdate" action, which will in turn update item in Firebase you'd be in trouble.

Comment: `fb.db.ref...` is a function, that modifies firebase, it doesn't emit actions or anything else. Firebase will be emitting change events frequently and independently from the specific app actions. Does it mean, that app will crash each time, when there were more than one action created at the same moment?

Comment: Yes, sure, but you have bounded a listener that listens to events on the firebase and that listener is dispatching an action.
It means what it says: you cannot dispatch new actions from your reducers which kind of happens now (afaik). In other words, you absolutely can dispatch dozens of actions, but by design you only handle one at a time and while handling you cannot (from the reducer itself) queue next one.